# EPPlus causing warning "the number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe"

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I've looked quite a bit through StackOverflow but nothing seems to quite solve my problem.

In my C# program I have a string field which is sometimes just a number, sometimes a word. This string is the source for the cell value in the generated Excel document.

When the string contains a word, it works fine, when it contains say "2", I get the error.

`The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe`.

Most answers on SO rely on treating the cell as a number to get rid of this, but mines is only sometimes a number, and I don't want the column in Excel to contain different formattings for cells which are logically the same.

I've tried treating it as explicitly as a Text field using the "@" formatting but that doesn't work either.

`excelRange.Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";`

Any thoughts?

Update:

When I type 2 into Excel it treats it as a number. If I manually change the formatting to text, it works how I want without any errors. I'm not sure when I programmatically enter "2" and use the "@" formatting it doesn't do the same...

Update 2:

The code I'm using at the moment which works fine when it is not a string.

```
using (var excelRange = excelWorksheet.Cells[lastEmptyRow, 5])
{
    var value = task.Priority;
    excelRange.Value = value;
    excelRange.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
    excelRange.Style.Border.BorderAround(ExcelBorderStyle.Thin);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the cell NumberFormat as cell.Style.Numberformat.Format = "@"; this would force it to be treated as a string rather than a number even if you set the value as a number.

Comment: I have unfortunately, but it still gives the same error. I checked the formatting in Excel and it does agree it's Text but still complains.

Comment: i meant something like https://gist.github.com/Digvijay/d76269e3dc6e09762397cba9c4817a07

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. I referred to it in my description, but did not include a code snippet, so maybe it wasn't very clearly, sorry. I've updated it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142479/discussion-between-digvijay-and-geesh-so).

Comment: What type is `value`?

Comment: dear @Digvijay your answer really helped me. This thing: `code`cell.Style.Numberformat.Format = "@"; works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

*I get the error* - except it is not an error it is a warning that "The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe." which is exactly what you say you want, for consistency of the format with other data.

The error message can be turned off in Excel Options ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26484880/1505120)).

Answer (score 0):

[As @mason said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43585787/epplus-causing-warning-the-number-in-this-cell-is-formatted-as-text-or-preceded#comment74224405_43585787), pay attention to `value`'s **type**.

If it's a `string`, then the behavior you describe is not surprising.

And if the behavior you're describing is undesirable, then cast or parse `value` into an `int` or a `decimal`.